# Return Response Image in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5, laravel-7

I'm trying to create a mini `random` image generator, as a start I've tried :

```
Route::get('/img/UoJb9wl.png','Image@random');
```

All I did is to return this

```
return '<img src="/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" width="200">';
```

---

Then, I tested on the live site :

I see the image loaded if I go to the URL

```
https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/UoJb9wl.png
```

[image]

If I imported on a site like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/ohk9syna/) like this

```
<img src="https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/UoJb9wl.png">
```

I can't see it.

[image]

Why ?

---

## Edit

Try #2

```
return env('APP_URL').'/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg';
```

I return image path now

[image]

But I still nothing rendering in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/ohk9syna/) still

```
<img src="https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/UoJb9wl.png">
```

[image]

Comment: May be this is happen for header's content_type, `header('Content-Type: image/png');` your header's content_type may be not a image type, what's your controller code?

Comment: On your controller you can return an image like this method `return response($img_path)->header('Content-type','image/png');`

Comment: @EsTeAa I tried that, and now the page is not showing anything. https://i.imgur.com/DoAWTjU.png

Comment: It return path now `https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/UoJb9wl.png`

Result : https://i.imgur.com/PZgNRyD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working just because of the returning image source `<img src="/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" width="200">` is not available on your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/ohk9syna/), even it will not work on any other website because no one have the image on this relative path `/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg`. If you want to really do that you have to specify the full absolute path. `<img src="https://www.bunlongheng.com/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" width="200">`.

So your return statement could be.

```
return '<img src="env('APP_URL')/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" width="200">';
```

Or whatever you think is good to specify the absolute path.

**Further Explanation**

I have checked on the JSFiddle source code, you are using this link `https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/UoJb9wl.png` in the image src tag. It will not work at all if you even specify the absolute path.

```
<img src="https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/UoJb9wl.png">
```

When browser will try to populate the `src` tag it will send request to `https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/UoJb9wl.png` and the response code is `<img src="/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" width="200">` so browser will populate it like this.

```
<img src="<img src="/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" width="200">">
```

So you have to return only the image path in the request, if you want to use this route in the image's src.

```
return env('APP_URL')."/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg"
```

If you want to keep your return statement same with image tag, then you can't use that route in image's src. Just use in the div or any other html tag.

Comment: I tried a a full remote link and still not working.

Comment: Ok. I can try again.

Comment: @cyber8200, I have checked the source on your link `https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/UoJb9wl.png` it still not showing the absolute/full path.

Comment: I tried return full-path, and it's still not rendering in the JSfiddle. :(, unless, I copied the url over.

Comment: @cyber8200 you can read further Styx answer to understand how to handle both situations.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what he is returning full or relative, the problem is he is returning a string, instead of an image. @Styx solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 10):

That doesn't work because your controller returns not an image, but an HTML code.

When you use this address in your browser, it sends request to your server, server responds with HTML which contains `<img src="..."/>` with link to the actual image, so browser shows it.

When you try to use the same address in the `<img src="..."/>`, your server still returns HTML code which is not an image, so obviously it won't be shown.

---

1. You can always serve the image itself:

```php
function random()
{
  return response()->file(/* path to image file */);
}
```

2. You can check `Accept` header to determine what to respond:

```php
function random(Request $request)
{
  $accept = $request->header('Accept');
  if (strpos($accept, 'text/html') !== false) {
    return response()->html('<img ...');
  } elseif (strpos($accept, 'image/') !== false) {
    return response()->file(...);
  }
  abort(403, 'No content for requested type');
}
```

Comment: I think the first option is vastly superior, where it returns the image, and also has the similar effect to the 2nd option.

Comment: @YahyaUddin Yes, the first option is straightforward, but the second allows more fluidity.

Answer (score 4):

Your route /img/UoJb9wl.png is actually returning /assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg which is exactly as expected.

Your img tag won't work as you aren't requesting a picture, you are requesting a route which returns another img tag with the actual location of the image.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following file response because your request is throwing a string of image paths.

https://www.bunlongheng.com/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);

return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your URL using Postman and somehow it's showing a 404 error code even though it's outputting the actual URL.

Also, if you're using it directly, it should return an actual image.You could try this:

`return response()->file('/assets/fe/img/welcome.jpeg');`